# not able to use variable from decorator scope in python

Tags: python, django

I have user being retrieved in my functions so i just pull it out into a decorator, the problem is, python tells me user isn't defined but I thought functions that get decorated are able to use variables in the decorator scope with out them being passed in as parameters.

```
def authenticator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
       body = json.loads(request.body)
       usern = body["username"]
       passw = body["password"]
       from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
       user = authenticate(username = usern, password = passw)
       return f(request, *args, **kwargs)

   return decorator
```

Here's the stack trace I get thrown

```
    Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py" in inner
  45.             return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/krishna/Documents/irrigationwebserver/webserver/irrigationservice/utils.py" in decorator
  24.         return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/krishna/Documents/irrigationwebserver/webserver/irrigationservice/views.py" in checkMoistureProfile
  92.     if user is not None:

Exception Type: NameError at /checkMoistureProfile/
Exception Value: global name &#39;user&#39; is not defined
```

Comment: You need to use `request.user`

Comment: Why would you think that? No function in Python is able to access variables in its caller's scope since Python 2.2

Comment: @millimoose some video I watched on decorators said python takes a snapshot of the decorators scope so that you can use it in the functions you decorate

Comment: @Brandon That's not where the error occurs. In fact the OP didn't even post that code, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: @jacksexton Has the video demonstrated that? If so, can you link it? Because I think that's simply not true. Maybe they meant closures / nested functions, not decorators? Either way, Python scope is lexical, if the variable isn't defined in an enclosing lexical scope, it won't be there unless you use something like `inspect` which you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @millimoose https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVon4QaY4wo,  they go to mention it works in nested functions, and decorators are just synctatic sugar for decorators so I assumed they worked for decorators as well

Comment: @millimoose Yeah, I wasn't exactly sure where the error was happening given the lack of code in the question, but, user should be defined on request, even if it's anonymous.

Comment: E.g. in your example, `decorator()` would have access to variables declared in `authenticator()`. But `f()` won't be able to access variables declared in either.

Comment: Please add a time mark to the video link, I'm not sitting through ten minutes sifting for the part you mean.

Comment: @millimoose 3:10 is where he demonstrates it

Comment: Decorators aren't syntactic sugar for nested functions **at all**. They're syntactic sugar for a function call where the result is assigned to the argument. (-ish.) As you can see, the video demonstrates access to the enclosing *lexical* scope. Decorators don't change anything about Python's scoping rules, e.g. which variable is accessible where.

Comment: What decorators do: https://ideone.com/BQx1Sq - that, and not much else, really.